# FB.login limitations popup blocked

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript, authentication

On my Flex/Actionscript app I'm using FB.login, which started giving me a blank popup after inserting credentials. On IE it still works, but from what I read, this is the cause:

> Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup
>   window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click
>   event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.

I was thinking to show a Javascript popup and after user clicks on it execute FB.login and send data back to Actionsript. Will this  work?
On Actionscript I'm simply executing:
`Facebook.login(onLoginHandler,{perms:'friends_work_history'});`

Now, how can I call JS and then get login data back on Actionscript?

Answer (score 0):

If the blocker was the culprit, I think you wouldn't see the popup at all.

What's the structure of the code that gets the login status and then calls FB.login?

I had a similar problem. Turned out to be code in/around the FB.login callback that was causing the problem.

This is a good example of something (javascript) that works:  http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/08/how-to--improve-the-experience-for-returning-users/